# How to upgrade the ssh program on OS X 10.6.8?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, ssh, open-source

I would prefer to do this through the command line rather than downloading Macports. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to upgrade ssh?

Comment: Also note that once you download the installer package GUI program for Mac Ports you would then install openssh using the port command from the Terminal. Although you don't have to use the GUI installer to get macports see http://www.macports.org/install.php

Answer (score 2):

Note that [ssh](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/10.6/man1/ssh.1.html) on OS X is part of the default [OpenSSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSH) suite included with OS X. So to upgrade ssh you should upgrade the entire OpenSSH suite of programs to get a newer version of the ssh program.

Check out the [OpenSSH Portable version](http://www.openssh.org/portable.html)

1. Download load the version you want.

   > The portable OpenSSH follows development of the official version, but releases are not synchronized. Portable releases are marked with a 'p' (e.g. 4.0p1). The official OpenBSD source will never use the 'p' suffix, but will instead increment the version number when they hit 'stable spots' in their development.
2. Read the [Installation instructions](http://openbsd.mirrorcatalogs.com/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/INSTALL) carefully, before installing.

As noted there:

> **The OpenSSH provided here is designed to run on the following Unix operating systems:**
>
> AIX
>
> HP-UX
>
> Irix
>
> Linux
>
> NeXT
>
> SCO
>
> SNI/Reliant Unix
>
> Solaris
>
> Digital Unix/Tru64/OSF
>
> **Mac OS X**
>
> Cygwin
>
> ... and more are being added all the time.